# Run shell script before CMD on image with ENTRYPOINT

Tags: docker

I want to take an existing Docker image with a fairly complicated entrypoint file, and before it runs `exec “$@“` I want to run an additional shell script.

The image I’m specifically interested in is Postgres, but I think this question is generic to any image with a nontrivial entrypoint file.

Assuming my new image has a file like this added:

```
COPY before-cmd.sh /
```

I see two good ways of running before-cmd.sh before the base image’s CMD runs:

1. Override the base CMD from `CMD [“postgres”]` to `CMD sh /before-cmd.sh ; postgres`
2. Alter the existing docker-entrypoint.sh by doing something like `sed -i '/exec “$@“/source \/before-cmd.sh ; exec “$@“/' /docker-entrypoint.sh` to inject sourcing the new script right before the `exec “$@“` command. (My escaping is probably incomplete in that sed command)

The first one is certainly simpler, but are there downsides to running two commands in CMD? Is there a third, better way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: "After ENTRYPOINT but before CMD" doesn't make sense; they aren't two separate steps. When you set both an ENTRYPOINT and a CMD, and don't override the CMD from the command line, the ENTRYPOINT is used to run the CMD.

Comment: Anyhow, why not have your CMD be `sh -c 'source /before-cmd.sh; exec postgres'`? -- that's not adding something _before_ the CMD, though, it's adding something _to_ the CMD. (The big difference from your proposal is the `exec`, ensuring that `postgres` inherits the PID that Docker directly invoked; also, it ensures that postgres is started _by the same shell_ that `before-cmd.sh` ran in, so environment variables &c set in that file are honored)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah the title may not be perfect, but if you read the question your suggestion is one option I’m considering.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I updated the title.

Comment: Have you considered an alternative entrypoint that wraps your first one by adding an extra step to it?

Comment: I’m happy to wrap the original entrypoint, but would rather not alter the original file. So if I change the Dockerfile to `ENTRYPOINT /wrapper-entrypoint.sh` that’s fine, but then that wrapper needs to run the original entrypoint first but not run its `exec “$@“` (and thereby prevent any following lines from running, if I understand exec correctly).

Comment: I've added a proper answer that describes the suggestion above in more detail.

Comment: BTW, one thing I maybe should have asked about is what `before-cmd` is actually doing. If it's setting environment variables, f/e, then not all of the options I showed in my answer will work. (Specifically, the one that _won't_ work in that case is the one that uses `sh -c '/before-cmd; exec "$@"'` -- in that case you'd want `before-cmd` to be a shell library instead of an executable and use `sh -c '. /before-cmd.sh; exec "$@"'` -- the `.sh` is correct there for a library -- or go with the first approach in the answer, the one that makes `before-cmd` be a wrapper with a final `exec` itself).

Comment: Does anything prevent you from editing the existing entrypoint script, adding this command invocation to it, and committing that to source control before you build the image?

Comment: @DavidMaze I’d rather not do that, because then any future changes to the entrypoint in the base image (Postgres)  will not automatically make it into my derived image.

Comment: If it's the `postgres` image specifically, is it enough to put the script in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`, and not try to change the entrypoint at all?  It will run once on first-time database initialization and not on every startup, but that might meet your practical needs.

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm specifically looking to run something every time the container starts, not just the first time the database is initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider creating a `/extended-entrypoint` (the below presumes you remove the `.sh` extensions, as [those are categorically bad practice](https://www.talisman.org/%7Eerlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/))

---

If you're willing to rewrite `before-cmd` to make it a wrapper itself, that might look like:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
exec /docker-entrypoint /before-cmd "$@"
```

(ensuring that `before-cmd` ends in `exec "$@"` itself -- optionally, `[ "$#" -gt 0 ] && exec "$@"` if you want to make that optional)

---

Otherwise, `extended-entrypoint` might look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /docker-entrypoint sh -c '/before-cmd; exec "$@"' "$0" "$@"
```

---

Either of the two will require only the same modification of the Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT /extended-entrypoint
```

The key advantage here is that your new, extended entrypoint *retains the basic nature of an entrypoint* of running before the CMD *even if the CMD is itself overridden at runtime*.

(Note that the above does not invoke `sh` explicitly anywhere, except when we're using `-c` to run a command line: running `sh executable` instead of just `executable` is an actively harmful practice that prevents executables from being able to select their own interpreter, and thus makes it impossible to reimplement software in a different language without needing to also modify everything that *invokes* that software; this does require using correct shebangs and marking your executables *as executable*, but you should be doing both those things anyhow).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. It taught me a lot. I won’t get a chance to try this out until probably Monday, but will accept the answer then assuming all goes well.